# AndroidKeyStore strange behaviour

Tags: android, security, encryption, keystore, android-keystore

I want to use the AndroidKeyStore in order to save an RSA keypair only on samsung device with Lollipop.
I know that the default android implementation has a bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61989) but it seems that on Samsung Lollipop devices it's fixed. But I see two other strange behaviour.
The RSA keypair is created using the following code:

```
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(ctx)
            .setAlias(ALIAS)
            .setSubject(
                    new X500Principal(String.format("CN=%s, OU=%s", ALIAS,
                            ctx.getPackageName())))
            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).setStartDate(notBefore.getTime())
            .setEndDate(notAfter.getTime()).build();

KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

And this is the code that open the KeyStore

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(ALIAS, null);

if (keyEntry != null) {
     return (RSAPrivateKey) keyEntry.getPrivateKey();
}
```

Issue n.1 : on Android emulator and on a CyanogenMod 12.1 device the keystore is unlocked at device boot EVEN IF the user did not insert the unlock PIN-PASSWORD-PATTERN and my test application can access the keystore. On Samsung devices instead the keystore is locked until the user dismiss the keyguard for the first time. The key must be encrypted using an AES key derived from PIN or PASSWORD and without user interaction the keystore must be locked

Issue n.2: on all devices it is possible to insert a keypair even if no secure lock screen is enabled, without any warning like "You must configure a screen lock method" by the OS. As above the key must be encrypted and without a screen lock it might be impossible to do it.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What devices are "all devices" (device and OS version)? Is the Samsung device KNOX enabled?

Comment: With "all devices" I mean all Samsung devices with lollipop + some Samsung with kk + LG with lollipop + simulator with lollipop. Knox never enabled

Answer (score 0):

@nikolay-elenkov suggests me to use KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.setEncryptionRequired() in order to encrypt keys at test and now ALL devices ask for a secure screenlock when a keypair is created and at boot time the keystore is locked until the user insert the Pin-Password-Pattern. Now it's ok! Thanks to @nikolay-elenkov as usual

The interesting thing is that Samsung devices with Lollipop and a secure screenlock enabled have the encryption enabled by default without using setEncryptionRequired. This is why I see the strange behavour on "Issue n.1" ... as usual a "strange" Samsung customization

Comment: setEncryptionRequired works only on LOLLIPOP device. On old devices (note3 neo with android 4.4.2 and S4 mini with 4.4.2) a popup with "Enter password for credential storage" (which password????) is shown when a keypair is loaded in KeyStore and there is not a screenlock setted up. But it does not matter because of KitKat bug (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61989) and my solution will only available for Android > 5.0